# Linq to entities projection into IEnumerable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I encountered problem with mapping `Roles` property, so it corresponds to `UserViewModel`.

```
var userManager = Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new ApplicationDbContext()));

var users = (from u in userManager.Users
             join r in roleManager.Roles
             on u.Id equals r.Id         
             select new UserViewModel { Id = u.Id, Username = u.UserName, Password = u.PasswordHash, Roles = select new Role { Name = r.Name }});

public class UserViewModel
{
   public string Id { get; set; }
   public string Username { get; set; }
   public string Password { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

How should I make Linq to Entities projection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the way you have your query setup it most likely not going to work you need a sub-query since you need to return a item/list with list i would do something like

Since you are using different contexts you can try to do the following 
I would advise you have some kind of using statement so you would clean your memory but you can convert it using to list to actual memory objects and then filter memory objects (just make sure your data is not to big)

```
 var userManager = Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>().Users.ToList();

var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new ApplicationDbContext())).Roles.ToList();


var users = (from u in userManager.Users       
              select new UserViewModel
              {  
                    Id = u.Id, 
                    Username = u.UserName, 
                    Password = u.PasswordHash,
                    Roles =(from r in  roleManager.Roles 
                             where r.Id==u.Id
                             select new Role
                             { 
                                 Name  = r.Name
                              }).ToList());
```

Comment: Tried that kind of subquery but it's always "The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts." as in this case.

Comment: Working now, removed Roles from `r in roleManager.Roles` as you specify it directly in `var userManager`. In current setup calling ToList is fine.

Comment: Just make sure it not a big return I would also user to list on the actual users and the dispose roles and users after I get the result